# R: Aligning factors across datasets

Tags: r

I have two datasets, a small modeling set, and a larger data to be scored.

In both datasets, I have multiple variables which are categorical in nature. (I am reading them from .csv files.)

How can I align the factors across these two datasets? If I do not align, the randomforest model I create on the modeling dataset cannot be applied on the dataset to be scored with the error -

```
Type of predictors in new data do not match that of the training data.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "align the factors"? Do they have different `levels()` in each of the data.frames? Also when it says "type" that makes me think the `class()` of the predictors might be different. Also make sure your variable names exactly match. If you could `dput` the heads of the two files, that might help us understand how they are different.

Comment: Don't bring them in as factors. After they are both in your workspace, create the columns using levels = unique( c(col1, col2) )

Comment: @BondedDust But wouldn't that mean one data.frame has levels the other does not? If you trained on a dataset that didn't have a particular value for a predictor, can you really predict into that level in the testing data set?